# How to put files and folders on umbraco webpage

Tags: umbraco7

I am using Umbraco for the first time. I want to put folders and sub folders and pdf files on my webpage for a "Public Access Documents page". Something like this :

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

You could create a media folder structure called documents then a child folder called meeting minutes with children folders of the year. To get the document paths you would need code something like this (10 would be the id of your Documents node - get this from the URL in the backend):

```
    @foreach (var documentType in Umbraco.TypedMedia(10).Children)
{
  foreach (var year in documentType.Children)
  {
    foreach (var document in year.Children)
    {
      @document.Url
    }
  }
}
```

In terms of the styling and how it looks there are frameworks like bootstrap which will give you a base on how it's looks on the frontend.

Comment: I did all this, but I still cannot see my document on the webpage. How do I make it appear on the webpage ?

Comment: Make sure the template is set correctly and wrap the razor in HTML. i.e. <p>@document.Url</p>